# Can my Andoid access an external SD card connected by USB C?

Tags: external-sd, 7.0-nougat

I am speaking about an ***external*** SD card, attached by USB C cable; not any internal SD card.

I realize that access speed would not be great, but I am just looking for a cheap way to carry around 256gB or so in my pocket, for quite infrequent access to large files.

Can my Android 7 device recognize that external storage, either alone, or with help of an app?

---

[Update] The device is a [ULEfone Armor 2](http://ulefone.com/products/armor2/features.html). I would want to use a USB C cable to connect to an external SD card reader (unless anyone knows of a cheaper way to connect lots of external storage (physically, not requiring network access))

Comment: It depends on the phone. Please [edit] your question and mention what phone you have. Also, I assume you mean the SD card is in a USB-C card reader, but the question makes it sound like you are expecting to attach the card to the cable directly.

Comment: A phone supporting OTG should recognize it as a regular storage device like any other USB drive, but if you're looking to have it recognize it as a SD card inserted into the device (e.g. so you could adopt it as internal storage) then that's not it.

Comment: I just want to be able to show a few photos or movies from an SD card which I carry around in pocket, along with an adapter/reader & USB-C cable. I think that you are correct, and that [OTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) will cover it. I was hoping that someone could confirm this.

Comment: For that purpose it should work if USB OTG works on your device. I have seen that images (in a DCIM directory structure) from an OTG SD card reader even appear in the gallery app. Just buy a cheap USB 2.0 sd-card reader plus OTG cable and try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this on a Pixel 3 with a VAVA Usb C hub and it did not work for me, even though other USB devices were recognized correctly through the hub.

Comment: Welcome aboard, and thanks for the feedback, after all this time :-)